# How to add conditional postbuild actions using jenkins Declarative Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, post-build-event

I need to check a condition before the job triggers the postbuild action

I could see that post section within the Pipeline supports always, changed, failure, success, unstable, and aborted. as the post build conditions. But i want to check another condition in the post build action. I tried with when{} but it’s not supported in post build action.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a script tag inside post build action and can use if() to check your condition

```
post {
 failure {
     script{
       if( expression ){
          //Post build action which satisfy the condition  
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

You can also add post build action for a **stage** in the pipeline also. In that case you can specify the condition in the **when**

```
pipeline {
stages {
    stage('Example') {
        when {
            //condition that you want check
        }
        steps {
        }
        post { //post build action for the stage
            failure { 
            //post build action that you want to check
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said. The `when` option is not available in the post section. To create a condition you can just create a scripted block inside the post section like in this example:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'xxx' } }

    environment {
        STAGE='PRD'
    }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3', artifactNumToKeepStr: '1'))
    }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "hello world"'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            script {
                if (env.STAGE == 'PRD') {
                    echo 'PRD ENVIRONMENT..'
                } else {
                    echo 'OTHER ENVIRONMENT'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the env var of STAGE is PRD it will print `PRD ENVIRONMENT` in the post section. If it isn't it will print: `DIFFERENT ENVIRONMENT`.

Run with `STAGE='PRD'`:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo 'hello world'
hello world
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
PRD ENVIRONMENT..
```

Run where `STAGE='UAT'` (you can use a parameter instead of a env var of course):

```
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo 'hello world'
hello world
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
OTHER ENVIRONMENT
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```